# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string Laravel 5

Tags: laravel

I have a problem when i make a query in blade laravel 5

```
 @foreach($dates_chart_debit as $date)
<?php

$result =  DB::table('productions')
->join('durees', 'productions.duree_id', '=', 'durees.id')
->where(DB::raw("Date(productions.date)") ,"=",$date)
->where('productions.puit_id' ,"=",1)
->where(DB::raw("durees.isInReport") ,"=",'1')
->where('final_validation' ,"=",'1')
->select(DB::raw("sum(debit) as debit"))->first()->get();
?>

{{$result->debit}}
@endforeach
```

it gives me an error message like

```
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string (View: C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\projects\Coil\resources\views\panel\chart\executive.blade.php)
```

and what is the best way to do that

Comment: What does var_dump($result); show?

Comment: the problem in the query i remove {{$result->debit}} and the same error

Comment: I'm asking what output of var_dump($result) is - it will help debug the issue...

Comment: the same error  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string (View: C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\projects\Coil\resources\views\panel\chart\executive.blade.php)

Comment: What is the value of `$date` ?

Comment: the value of $dates_chart_debit is     array:3 [
  0 => {#235
    +"date": "2016-07-14"
  }
  1 => {#236
    +"date": "2016-07-20"
  }
  2 => {#237
    +"date": "2016-07-29"
  }
]

Comment: when i try to put default value of $date it show me nothing             
The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will be displayed with incorrect characters for some browser configurations if the document contains characters outside the US-ASCII range. Encoding page of characters must be stated in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is coming from the $date variable - You are attempting to pass an object into the query and convert it to a string.

Your comment

> the value of $dates_chart_debit is array:3 [ 0 => {#235 +"date": "2016-07-14" } 1 => {#236 +"date": "2016-07-20" } 2 => {#237 +"date": "2016-07-29" } ]

Confirms this.

If you replaced the:

```
->where(DB::raw("Date(productions.date)") ,"=",$date)
```

with:

```
->where(DB::raw("Date(productions.date)") ,"=",2016-07-14)
```

Does it work?

Also - Can you do dd($date); for me please?

Comment: i dont know because a have i problem in javascript   it show me a blank page

Answer (score 0):

I use Chart Js

when i try to put default value of $date it show me nothing The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will be displayed with incorrect characters for some browser configurations if the document contains characters outside the US-ASCII range. Encoding page of characters must be stated in the document or in the transfer protocol.

```js
var areaChartData = {
                labels: [
                    @if(isset($dates_chart_debit))
                           @foreach( $dates_chart_debit as $dd)
                                "{{$dd->date}}",
                            @endforeach
                     @endif
                    ],
                datasets: [
                        @if(isset($puits_chart_debit ))
                            @foreach($puits_chart_debit as $puit)
                            {
                                    label: "{{$puit->code}}",
                                    fillColor: "{{$puit->color}}",
                                    strokeColor: "{{$puit->color}}",
                                    pointColor: "{{$puit->color}}",
                                    pointStrokeColor:"{{$puit->color}}",
                                    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                                    pointHighlightStroke: "{{$puit->color}}",
                                    data: [

                                    @foreach($dates_chart_debit as $date)
                                       <?php

                                             $result =  DB::table('productions')
                                                    ->join('durees', 'productions.duree_id', '=', 'durees.id')
                                                    ->where(DB::raw("Date(productions.date)") ,"=",$date->date)
                                                    ->where('productions.puit_id' ,"=",1)
                                                    ->where(DB::raw("durees.isInReport") ,"=",'1')
                                                    ->where('final_validation' ,"=",'1')
                                                    ->select(DB::raw("sum(debit) as debit"))->first()->get();


                                            dd($result->debit);
                                       ?>


                                    @endforeach
                                           ]
                            },
                            @endforeach
                        @endif
                    ]
            };
```